# Level of interaction of ginger tea/ginger powder and aspirin

Tags: drug-interactions, tea, bleeding, cooking

It seems that there is some interaction between ginger and aspirin from what I read online. Here is [an example](https://www.mountsinai.org/health-library/herb/ginger#:%7E:text=Possible%20Interactions&text=Blood%2Dthinning%20medications%3A%20Ginger%20may,(Plavix)%2C%20or%20aspirin.):

> Ginger may interact with prescription and over-the-counter medicines. If you take any of the following medicines, you should not use ginger without talking to your health care provider first.
>
> **Blood-thinning medications:**
>
> Talk to your doctor before taking ginger if you take blood thinners,
> such as warfarin (Coumadin), clopidogrel (Plavix), or aspirin.Ginger may increase the risk of bleeding.

What I am trying to understand is the following: if someone has a ginger tea or add ginger powder as spice in a meal, if for some reason in that same day later the person needs to take an aspiring would that cause a problem? Would an interaction mean e.g. wait 24 hour from the ginger tea or meal with powder and taking the aspirin (to generalize any other medicine that would interact with ginger).
I am asking out of curiosity because I know ginger is a heavily used herb in some countries.

Comment: Why is this question closed? This is a general inquiry. It's not related to something I am doing

Comment: You may not have intended to ask for personal medical advice, but in fact, by using the "If I...then might I...?" language, it becomes a request for personal medical advice. If a friend asked that question, I would put it in that category. If a friend asked, "Hey, I read in {x magazine) that ginger root and aspirin can't be taken together. Are you familiar with why that is?" I would not consider that as a request for personal advice. That's not what you asked, though. Words matter.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I updated the post. Is it better now for reopening?

Comment: If you include a link to the source where you read this, I believe the moderator *might* reopen the question, but I'm not a moderator. Usually we ask that you link to a source attempting to *answer* the question.

Comment: "from what I read online" -- Like what? Link us to an example and a short quote. I did a quick search on aspirin+ginger and you're right that there are interactions and warnings about them from credible sources. It should be very easy for you to find some and you need to because prior research is required here and your question shows none.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Updated the post

Comment: Thank you but quoting some random guy's blog isn't what we have in mind here when we ask for credible sources. I've edited your question to provide the very first hit you get if you type aspirin + ginger into google and reopened it based on that.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Thank you!

Comment: @smith - I tried to find you an answer, but could not. There are a *very* few case reports on significant anti-platelet activity with ginger, and a fair amount of speculation, but no good studies and no conclusions except the potential for interaction. Aspirin is a weak but permanent inhibitor of platelet aggregation, and physicians recommend to stop taking aspirin a week before surgical procedures, but one study showed platelet "recovery" (enough new platelets to stop minor bleeding) at 96 hours. So, no, no answers for this question.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: thank you. So if I understand correctly, taking extreme caution would mean that someone has to wait for at least 96-hours to a week after taking an aspirin to consume a ginger tea/ginger powder in meal? Would also the reverse hold? I.e. wait 96 hours to a week from consuming ginger to taking an aspirin?

Comment: @smith - No, the reverse is not necessarily true, nor is the first statement necessarily true. I stated there was a fair amount of speculation, but no solid evidence. The question remains unanswered in the English language literature that I have searched.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: by necessarily true, you mean the 96 hour period might be unnecessary?

Comment: Again, you are asking me for medical advice, which I'm absolutely not going to give you. What part of "speculation" is confusing to you? Do you think there is a known and single answer to everything? There's not. The world, including medicine, is full of exceptions to everything. Nothing is certain but death and taxes.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I am only trying to come up with some answer. Basically you are saying there is no evidence there is an interaction, only some theories. Based on that I am trying to understand in such cases what is the usual stance in general. E.g. I guess someone can lean to either extreme? I.e. completely ignore or be completely paranoid. Again this is not med advice. I am just asking because there are countries that consume a lot of ginger and I am interested what's going on

Comment: If there are countries that consume a lot of both ginger and aspirin, and folks aren't keeling over by the thousands from strokes or bleeding to death, there must not be a strong combined anticoagulant effect, right? Or, they *are*, and it's not recognized to be the cause. You're trying to put words in my mouth that don't belong there. To form your own opinion, please search the literature yourself, using Google Scholar, you'll get better info that way. (This is what I get by trying to help. Lesson learned. Finally.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I didn't have any intention to put words in your mouth. I understand now that this SE is not the same as the others. I am not related to the medical field so I guess my phrasing is "too relaxed"/not appropriate for this SE. I thought I might try to convert the comments in some form of answer but I understand what you mean now. Thanks for your help and input